# Why isn't my try catch block throwing an exception?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function which checks if number is positive. I want it throw an exception if `a < 0`

```
function isPositive(a) {
  try{
    switch(a) {
      case a < 0:
      throw 'Too small';
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
isPositive(-3)
```

Comment: You can't use case with a condition, you should simply use a if statement

Comment: @Axnyff: You *can*, but you shouldn't 99.999% of the time. At least. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're misusing `switch`. The value you switch on must be `===` the value in a case expression. In your example, `a` (-3) is not `===` the result of the expression `a < 0` (which is `true`).

`switch` isn't the right tool here, use `if`:

```js
function isPositive(a) {
  try{
    if (a < 0) {
      throw 'Too small';
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
isPositive(-3)
```

...but if you **really** wanted to use `switch`, you could (in JavaScript) because JavaScript's `switch` is a bit different from C's, Java's, or C#'s: You'd use `switch (true)` so that it would match the expression `a < 10`:

```js
function isPositive(a) {
  try{
    switch (true) {
      case a < 0:
        throw 'Too small';
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
isPositive(-3)
```

The cases are tested in source code order, and the first matching case wins.

But again: `if` is the correct thing here, not `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

The way a `switch` statement works is:

1. First, the expression in the `switch` header (in parentheses) is evaluated.
2. Next, each `case` expression is evaluated and compared with that value for exact equality. If a `case` is found whose expression is exactly equal, execution picks up with the code for that `case`.
3. If no `case` matches, the `default` code runs (if it's there).

In your code, the value of the `switch` expression will be `-3`, and the value of the expression on the first `case` will be `true`. Because `true` is not exactly equal to `-3`, the code doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your switch around, literally check for true so you can evaluate each line.

```
function isPositive(a) {
  try{
    switch(true) {
      case a < 0:
      throw 'Too small';
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
isPositive(-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you have to set the value switch evaluates to true:

```
switch(true){ // your code }
```

Then the code inside will run and the error should be thrown